# Compile error while sorting array of custom structs

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I made this simple example for sorting an array of my custom struct `s`. It has an `operator<` function, and, according to [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), this is all that's needed to `sort`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

struct s {
    int number;
    bool operator<(s& other) {
        return this->number < other.number;
    }
};

int main() {
    s arr[10];
    std::sort(arr[0], arr[9]);
}
```

However, when trying to compile I get several errors:

```
error C2676: binary '-': 'const _RanIt' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
error C2672: '_Sort_unchecked': no matching overloaded function found
error C2780: 'void std::_Sort_unchecked(_RanIt,_RanIt,iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type,_Pr)': expects 4 arguments - 3 provided
```

I have already found out that this only happens with arrays, but works with e.g. vectors. Why do these errors occur and how do I fix them?

Comment: Try `std::sort(arr, arr+9);` `arr[0]` is a number, not an adress

Comment: `bool operator<(const s& other) const { return this->number < other.number; }` Don't ignore `const`.

Comment: And it should be `arr+10`. `arr+9` misses the last element of the array.

Comment: ... and `#include <iterator>` then do `std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`

Comment: [This is a much better reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  Second, if you go to that link, the parameters you must pass are iterators, not values from the array.  A pointer serves as an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::sort` takes iterators as parameters not elements of the array.

Consider that this cannot work to sort an array:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};  // the array
std::sort(1,4);       // pass first and last element to sort...urks
```

Pointers to elements in c-arrays are iterators, you can get them conveniently with [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end):

```
s arr[10];
std::sort(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr));
```